# Ошибка при регистрации юзера в django-rest-framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

При попытке регистрации выдает ошибку :
TypeError at /api/v1/rest-auth/registration/
save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

вот Traceback:https://pastebin.com/t6CmR4Pv

serializer.py

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'username','password','avatar')
```

views.py

```
class UserListView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = models.CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer
```

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=f"{MEDIA_ROOT}avatars", blank=True)
    rss_subscription = models.ManyToManyField(RssList)
    labels = models.ManyToManyField(Labels,blank=True)
    
    def __srt__(self):
        return self.email
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему ошибка в этой строчке:

```
File "/home/ser/Документы/pythonPR/DjangoPR/django+vue(RSS agregator)/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_auth/registration/views.py", line 73, in perform_create
    user = serializer.save(self.request)
```

Выгдядит так как будто `serializer.save()` не принимает никаких параметров: но получает аргумент `self.request`.

Если это Ваш код, `rest_auth/registration/views.py`, то замените 73 строку на `user = serializer.save()`

Если код не Ваш, то попробуйте обновить пакеты через pip на последние версии.

**UPDATE:** Пакет `rest-auth` устарел, он не обновлялся с 1 Apr 2019, поэтому вам придется откать `Django` и `django-rest-framework` назад. Или отказаться от использования `rest-auth`. Удачи!

Comment: Код не мой, сейчас попробую обновить.

Comment: Все пакеты последней версии. Ошибка та же.

Comment: Значит Вам предстоит новая игра - найти версии пакетов, при которой код работает друг с другом. Откатывайте django-rest-framework назад, на старые версии, пока код не заработает.

Comment: Спасибо ,сейчас буду тогда искать эту версию drf.